# Is there an svg source of icons for FontAwesome?

Tags: font-awesome, sketch-3

I need SVG sources for icons so I can use them in sketch for mockups. However it seems as if there's no SVG library like Google's Material Icons, only the code for integration.

Comment: http://fontello.com/ Select Font-Awesome icons and download zip. It will be all in one SVG file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the version 5 will have a SVG SDK, however meanwhile, you can use https://icomoon.io/app/ to export SVGs from Font Awesome (and other packs) icons.

Answer (score 0):

There is now (as of version 5). Free icons [here](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/js/all.js). [This](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/jquery) outlines how to use them.